# Removing git branches which are old and created temporarily

Tags: git, github

I want to script a functionality to maintain our git repo. I want to delete the branches which have not been touched for a duration. I can just look at the commit history and ask the creator of the branch to delete it, but let's say he has merged another branch after his coding and then he did not do anything. So how can I detect the owner of the branch in that case?

Please any idea regarding this will help me.

Comment: Read about [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). The ["Pretty Formats"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) section could give you some ideas.

Comment: Can you clarify the last couple sentences of your post? It is currently somewhat unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: In `git`, branches don't have owners. They have an arbitrary (and usually non-empty) set of committers who have contributed commits in the DAG whose HEAD is currently pointed to by the branch reference.

Comment: Hi Scott, The requirement is actually to figure out which branch of my git repo is not in use and who should be contacted in order to delete those branches.

Comment: Twalberg - Owner means I meant who all did commit to a specific branch. Sometimes developers do commit and then merge there branch with another head production branch. So we should capture only them who are making any changes in a branch.

Comment: You could do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420662/2303202) instead, so developer would not be stressed into thinking do they need those branches or not.

Comment: max630 - Thats cool practice I think. I will explore this more. Thanks.